# Using perl XML::LibXML to deal with XML so slowly

Tags: xml, perl

The XML file is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resource-data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="resource-data.xsd">
  <class name="AP">
    <attributes>
      <resourceId>00 11 B5 1B 6D 20</resourceId>
      <lastModifyTime>20130107091545</lastModifyTime>
      <dcTime>20130107093019</dcTime>
      <attribute name="NMS_ID" value="DNMS" />
      <attribute name="IP_ADDR" value="10.11.141.111" />
      <attribute name="LABEL_DEV" value="00 11 B5 1B 6D 20" />
    </attributes>
        <attributes>
      <resourceId>00 11 B5 1B 6D 21</resourceId>
      <lastModifyTime>20130107091546</lastModifyTime>
      <dcTime>20130107093019</dcTime>
      <attribute name="NMS_ID" value="DNMS" />
      <attribute name="IP_ADDR" value="10.11.141.112" />
      <attribute name="LABEL_DEV" value="00 11 B5 1B 6D 21" />
    </attributes>
  </class>
</resource-data>
```

And my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Encode;
use XML::LibXML;
use Data::Dumper;

$parser = new XML::LibXML;
$struct = $parser->parse_file("d:/AP_201301073100_1.xml");

my $file_data = "d:\\ap.txt";
open IN, ">$file_data";

$rootel = $struct->getDocumentElement();
$elname = $rootel->getName();

@kids   = $rootel->getElementsByTagName('attributes');
foreach $child (@kids) {
  @atts = $child->getElementsByTagName('attribute');
  foreach $at (@atts) {
    $va = $at->getAttribute('value');
    print IN encode("gbk", "$va\t");
  }
  print IN encode("gbk", "\n");
}
close(IN);
```

My question is, if the XML file is only 80MB then then program will be very fast, but when the XML file is much larger the program can then be very slow. Can somebody help me speed this up please?

Comment: I think a [stream](http://coldattic.info/shvedsky/pro/blogs/a-foo-walks-into-a-bar/posts/55) based parser is recommended for large xml files

Comment: i just need to how to modify my program ,can you help me .

Comment: btw, use `open IN, ">:encoding(gbk)", $file_data;` instead of encoding all over the place.

Comment: @John Im sorry I have limited experience with XML parsing and none at all with SAX parsers, maybe you can google for tutorials. [XML::Twig_101](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.42/Twig_pm.slow#XML::Twig_101) is a start.

Comment: You must *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the head of your program, and declare all variable at their first point of use using `my`. And `IN` seems a strange name for an output stream!

Comment: Related: [Serially process XML data in perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133312/serially-process-xml-data-in-perl)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another possibility is to use [XML::LibXML::Reader](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML::Reader). It works similarly to SAX, but uses the same `libxml` library as XML::LibXML:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::LibXML::Reader;

my $reader = XML::LibXML::Reader->new(location => '1.xml');

open my $OUT, '>:encoding(gbk)', '1.out';

while ($reader->read) {
    attr($reader) if 'attributes' eq $reader->name
                     and XML_READER_TYPE_ELEMENT == $reader->nodeType;
}

sub attr {
    my $reader = shift;
    my @kids;
  ATTRIBUTE:
    while ($reader->read) {
        my $name = $reader->name;
        last ATTRIBUTE if 'attributes' eq $name;
        next ATTRIBUTE if XML_READER_TYPE_END_ELEMENT == $reader->nodeType;
        push @kids, $reader->getAttribute('value')
            if 'attribute' eq $name;
    }
    print {$OUT} join("\t", @kids), "\n";
}
```

Comment: thanks ,this way very fast,just about one minutes can convert the xml file to txt.

Answer (score 6):

Using [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::Twig) will allow you to process each `<attributes>` element as it is encountered during parsing, and then discard the XML data that is no longer needed.

This program seems to do what you need.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;
use Encode;

use constant XML_FILE => 'S:/AP_201301073100_1.xml';
use constant OUT_FILE => 'D:/ap.txt';

open my $outfh, '>:encoding(gbk)', OUT_FILE or die $!;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(twig_handlers => {attributes => \&attributes});
$twig->parsefile('myxml.xml');

sub attributes {
  my ($twig, $atts) = @_;
  my @values = map $_->att('value'), $atts->children('attribute');
  print $outfh join("\t", @values), "\n";
  $twig->purge;
}
```

**output**

```
DNMS  10.11.141.111 00 11 B5 1B 6D 20
DNMS  10.11.141.112 00 11 B5 1B 6D 21
```

Comment: thanks ,I've tested ,it can run,but takes more time than choroba's answer.thanks,both of you are brilliant

Answer (score 0):

If you have XML files that are this large - 80MB+, you cannot parse whole file into memory - first, it is very slow, second, it will eventually run out of memory and your program will crash.

I would suggest to rewrite your code using [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aTwig) and using callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

For large XML files you must use a stream-based parser like [`XML::SAX`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aSAX), because DOM parsers build the entire XML structure in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way with [XML::Rules](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aRules):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Rules;
use Data::Dumper;

my @rules = (
  attribute => [ attributes => sub { print "$_[1]{value}\n"; return } ],
  _default => undef,
);

my $xr = XML::Rules->new( rules => \@rules );
my $data = $xr->parse($xml);
```